# What should I do if an answer is wrong, but I don't have time to calculate the right answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I saw this question:
*[Find the concentration of proton after adding a acid to NaOH](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/97527/find-the-concentration-of-proton-after-adding-a-acid-to-naoh)*
(before it was put on hold) where I was pretty sure that the chosen answer is incorrect. (For non-chemists: the chosen answer assumes that each molecule of H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub> is donating both protons ("each H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub> mol gives 2 H<sub>3</sub>O+ mols"). But in a solution of sulfuric acid, all molecules donate the *first* proton, but only some of the molecules donate the second proton.)

However, in order to edit the answer and replace it with a *correct* answer, I would have to make an "initial/change/equilibrium" chart and solve a quadratic equation, and I didn't have time on the fly to do that. And you're only supposed to leave an "answer" if it's an attempt at a complete and correct answer; you're not supposed to just leave an answer that's a response to another answer. And I didn't have enough reputation to leave a comment. So I did nothing.

What should a user do in that situation? If you believe that an answer is probably incorrect, but you don't have time to calculate the right answer (or maybe you don't know *how* to get the correct answer, but you know enough to know the existing answer is wrong), you are still contributing positively if you mark the incorrect answer as incorrect. Is there a way to do that, if you can't leave a comment?

If there is no way to do that, then I would suggest this as a feature request.  There should be a way to leave feedback for the user who posted an answer, suggesting that the answer is probably incorrect, even if you don't know how to calculate the correct answer completely. (And even if you do not have enough reputation to leave a comment.)

Comment: Just a quick comment: users technically are supposed to avoid answering questions that are likely to be put on hold. If the question author didn't properly demonstrate understanding of the problem, it decreases their chances of finding a good answer.

Comment: If you are changing an answer to the point where a formula is going from being incorrect to being correct, then that edit shouldn’t even be proposed.  If you don’t know the answer to a question you shouldn’t be doing anything.  You should downvote incorrect or incomplete answers

Comment: @Ramhound I don't understand what you mean by "If you are changing an answer to the point where a formula is going from being incorrect to being correct, then that edit shouldn’t even be proposed."  If I am changing a formula from being incorrect to correct, isn't that a good thing?  Why should that edit not be proposed?

Comment: @Bennett You would be fundamentally be changing what the authors answer.  The proper situation in that situation is to submit an answer yourself.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog thanks, OK I will keep that in mind for future reference.  However, the issue of "What to do if I know that the chosen answer is wrong but I still don't know how to get the right answer?" could just as easily come up for a question that is *not* a "homework question" and is not likely to be put on hold.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog also, I will add that the advice about "Don't answer homework questions" (or questions that are going to be put on hold generally) is something that actually doesn't appear in the pop-up that is displayed when you're about to type an answer, so there is no reason that new users would know this.  I've seen a couple of new users get aggravated because they provided what they thought was a helpful answer, they read the rules first, but they got downvoted because they violated the "unwritten rule" against answering homework questions, which on one told them about.

Comment: ... That's something to probably discuss on meta instead: when the pop-up appears to give you advice as you are writing an answer, the advice that it gives you should match what the community members actually want you to do (and what you'll be penalized for if you don't do it).

Comment: @Ramhound "If you don’t know the answer to a question you shouldn’t be doing anything."  If I am able to provide feedback that an existing answer is incorrect (even if I don't know the correct answer), that's better for the person who asked the question, better for the person who provided the incorrect answer, and better for users who will come along and read the question & answer later.  So it is a limitation in the site if there's no way to do this.

Comment: @Bennett - Feedback only goes so far, and only possible, if you can leave a comment.  It's really simply, If you don't have time to submit the correct answer, you shouldn't do anything.

Answer (score 7):

> There should be a way to leave feedback for the user who posted an answer, suggesting that the answer is probably incorrect, even if you don't know how to calculate the correct answer completely. (And even if you do not have enough reputation to leave a comment.)

There already is such a mechanism. It's the down-vote. Though it does require more reputation than that required to comment, so it's not a solution open to all.

If you have what you think is the correct answer then post it as your own answer. If it's a correction to a formula or a fixed piece of code this it's important not to change other people's answers - unless they're explicitly collaborative answers (Community Wiki).

Getting the necessary reputation points to comment isn't hard. It might look that way as you're starting out and struggling to find a question to answer, but with a bit of perseverance you should be able to find a couple of questions to answer and, as long as they're good answers, you'll have the points you need. Then you can comment.

I know it seems hard, but the system is designed to encourage participation and initially that's just the basics of asking, answering and up-voting. The other features - commenting, down-voting require you to stick around and get a better grasp of what the community is about before you can use the tools. By and large it works (not as well as we'd like perhaps, but...) even if there are edge cases like yours.

Comment: OK I will do that if I have what I think is the correct answer.  My question is about the case where I don't know how to find the correct answer, but I do know that the chosen answer (or any answer, even if it's not "chosen") is wrong, but I don't have enough reputation to comment.  It seems like in the current design of the site, there's nothing I can do and the wrong answer goes unchallenged.

Comment: Also I don't think it's that easy to gain reputation.  On Chemistry Stack Exchange, the current "new" questions are: "extraction of fatty matter from toilet soap" / "Combustion analysis" / "Diffusion experiment with dialysis membrane bag" etc.  The only one I know how to answer is the "Combustion analysis" question, but if I answer that one the answer will probably be downvoted because it's a homework question.  It looks like most non-trivial questions are difficult enough that you do have to be an expert to give the best answer.